# Multiple C threads not returning correct values

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to multiply two matrices using a different thread for each member of the resultant matrix. I have this code:

```
struct data{
    int p;
    int linie[20];
    int coloana[20];
};

void *func(void *args){

    struct data *st = (struct data *) args;
    int c = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < st->p; k++){
        c += st->linie[k] * st->coloana[k];
    }

    char *rez = (char*) malloc(5);
    sprintf(rez, "%d", c);

    return rez;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int n = 2;
    int m = 2;

    int A[2][2] = {{1, 2},  
                   {4, 5}};

    int B[2][2] = {{7, 3},  
                  {7, 5}};

    int C[n][m];

    char *res[n * m];
    char *rez[n * m];

    pthread_t threads[n * m];
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            struct data st;
            st.p = 2;
            for(int x = 0; x < st.p; x++){
                st.linie[x] = A[i][x];
                st.coloana[x] = B[x][j]; 
            }

            pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL, func, &st);   

            count++;
        }   
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n * m; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], (void**) &rez[i]);
        printf("%d ", atoi(rez[i]));

    }

    return 0;
}
```

But the correct result is never put into rez[i]. For example I get output "63 37 37 37". 
The code works perfectly if I don't choose to wait for every thread to finish, i.e. I put that pthread_join right after pthread_create in the nested for loop. What should I do?
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Please be careful and make sure the code you post could compile — I fixed a trivial syntax error for you (missing semicolon before end of `main()`).  Also, please indent your code.   Copy'n'paste indented code, then select it all and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it by 4 spaces.  That should look okay unless you were careless enough to use tabs instead of spaces.  Don't use tabs in the code you paste.

Answer (score 1):

Your first threading problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        struct data st;
        st.p = 2;
        for(int x = 0; x < st.p; x++){
            st.linie[x] = A[i][x];
            st.coloana[x] = B[x][j]; 
        }
        pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL, func, &st);   
        count++;
    }   
}
```

All the threads get passed a pointer to the same variable, `&st`, which goes out of scope after each call to `pthread_create()`.  You need to ensure that each thread gets its own variable, and that the variable lasts until the thread exits.

To fix this, for example, you could try:

```
struct data st[n * m];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        st[count].p = 2;
        for (int x = 0; x < st[count].p; x++)
        {
            st[count].linie[x] = A[i][x];
            st[count].coloana[x] = B[x][j]; 
        }
        int rc = pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL, func, &st[count]);
        if (rc != 0)
            …report pthread creation error…  
        count++;
    }   
}
```

This gives each thread its own `struct data` to work on, and the structure outlasts the `pthread_join()` loop.

I'm not completely that it is a good scheme to make one copy of the relevant parts of the two arrays for each thread.  It's not too painful at size 2x2, but at 20x20, it begins to be painful.  The threads should be told which row and column to process, and should be given pointers to the source matrices, and so on.  As long as no thread modifies the source matrices, there isn't a problem reading the data.

---

*Updated answer which replaces the previous invalid code related to `pthread_join()` (as noted by [oftigus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10688511/oftigus) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422467/multiple-c-threads-not-returning-correct-values/53422532#comment93720301_53422532)) with this working code.  There's a reason I normally test before I post!*

On the whole, casts like `(void **)` should be avoided in the `pthread_join()` loop.  One correct working way to handle this is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
    {
        void *vp;
        int rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &vp);
        if (rc == 0 && vp != NULL)
        {
            rez[i] = vp;
            printf("(%s) %d ", rez[i], atoi(rez[i]));
            free(rez[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
```

This passes a pointer to a `void *` variable to `pthread_join()`.  If it finds the information for the requested thread, then `pthread_join()` makes that `void *` variable hold the value returned by the thread function.  This can then be used as shown — note the error handling (though I note that the example in the POSIX specification for [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html)ignores the return value from `pthread_join()` with a `(void)` cast on the result).

---

I don't see where you use `res` or `C`.

---

The result I get is:

```
(21) 21 (13) 13 (63) 63 (37) 37
```

where the value in parentheses is a string and the value outside is converted by `atoi()`.  That looks like the correct answer for multiplying `A` by `B` (in that order).

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data
{
    int p;
    int linie[20];
    int coloana[20];
};

static void *func(void *args)
{
    struct data *st = (struct data *)args;
    int c = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < st->p; k++)
    {
        c += st->linie[k] * st->coloana[k];
    }

    char *rez = (char *)malloc(5);
    sprintf(rez, "%d", c);

    return rez;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 2;
    int m = 2;
    int A[2][2] = {{1, 2},  {4, 5}};
    int B[2][2] = {{7, 3},  {7, 5}};
    char *rez[n * m];

    pthread_t threads[n * m];
    int count = 0;
    struct data st[n * m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            st[count].p = 2;
            for (int x = 0; x < st[count].p; x++)
            {
                st[count].linie[x] = A[i][x];
                st[count].coloana[x] = B[x][j];
            }
            int rc = pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL, func, &st[count]);
            if (rc != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create thread %d for cell C[%d][%d]\n", count, i, j);
                exit(1);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n * m; i++)
    {
        void *vp;
        int rc = pthread_join(threads[i], &vp);
        if (rc == 0 && vp != NULL)
        {
            rez[i] = vp;
            printf("(%s) %d ", rez[i], atoi(rez[i]));
            free(rez[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, after changing to an array of structs it works perfectly. I tried to change the pthread_join() too but I got segmentation fault. Also thanks for the welcome, I'll make sure to read up the intro before I ask the next question. Have a nice day!

Comment: You were right!  The first code I posted for modifying the `pthread_join()` loop was wrong — completely and crashingly wrong.  I've updated it with correct code that doesn't crash and does produce the correct answer without the bludgeoning `(void **)` cast — it needs no cast, in fact.